# Can't read property 'concat' of undefined

Tags: javascript

```
function seven(m) {
// your codes
var numStr = m.toString();
var arrayS = arrayS = numStr.split('')
var steps = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < arrayS.length; i++) {

if(arrayS.length <= 2) {
  
} else {
  var lastElmArr = arrayS[arrayS.length - 1]
  var lastElmStr = lastElmArr.toString()
  var lastElmInt = parseInt(lastElmStr)
  
  arrayS.pop();
  
  var firstElms;
  for(let j = 0; j < arrayS.length; j++) {
    firstElms = firstElms.concat(arrayS[j]);
  }
}
}
return firstElms
}
```

[image: error code]

I can't understand why this happens and don't think this is the best way to pass an array to a number

Comment: firstElms seems to be undefined somehow.

Comment: The first time `firstElms.concat` is being executed, what do you think the value of `firstElms` is…?

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize the `firstElms` as an empty array like:

`var firstElms = [];`

and it should work fine.

Here is an working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0xje6n4w/1/).

Answer (score 1):

*UPDATE*

You are trying to concat a value to something that is not defined. So give initial value as empty for `firstElms`

```
    var firstElms ="";
     for(let j = 0; j < arrayS.length; j++) {
        firstElms = firstElms.concat(arrayS[j]);
      }
```